# Social networking sites static caching

Tags: browser, social-networks

In sites like facebook or orkut or friendster what's displayed at the bottom instead of main web address like static.ak.fbcdn.net or profile.ak.fbcdn.net? Are these  different servers or they are just used to misguide the hackers?

Answer (score 2):

They're different servers that are optimized to deliver particular types of content. For example, if you can segregate all the static content from the dynamic content, you can use a *very* fast specialized webserver to deliver the static content which can assume that all it does is just serve up data from files, but which can't write to any of them (in fact, you can configure the server so that it can't open any file at all for writing or overwrite any part of the program, making the server extremely hardened against attacks). Looking at the URL, I'd guess that the data is actually being served from a Content Delivery Network as well (i.e., a geographically distributed collection of identical servers).

However, it should be noted that *none* of that will fool hackers. Or anyone else with web development tools. The purpose is to optimize servers for delivering particular types of content, with particular risk profiles, load patterns, etc.

Comment: In addition, serving from a separate domain means the client doesn't have to send all it's cookies with every request. [Here](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/request.html) is a bunch more detail.

Answer (score 0):

What you're talking about are CDN's (Content Delivery Networks) that are used by Facebook to deliver static files (pictures, videos, gifs, music, etc).

The `ak` in the URL tells you that Facebook uses the Akamai CDN.